# Returning Multiple SQL Results to .handlebars using Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js, router

I am *very* new to Express and Node.js and am curious how to return multiple SQL results to elements of a page.

It is probably a straightforward question to answer, but I don't know how to proceed, and any help would be much appreciated.

So, I have the following `page1.js` file:

```js
module.exports = function(){
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();

   // Get the results of the first SQL statement
   function getMyTable(res, mysql, context, complete){
      mysql.pool.query("SELECT * from MyTable", function(error, results){
         if(error){
            res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
            res.end();
         }
         context.page1table = results;
         complete();
   }

   // Get the results of the second SQL statement
   function getMyList(res, mysql, context, complete){
      mysql.pool.query("SELECT DISTINCT class from MyTable", function(error, results){
         if(error){
            res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
            res.end();
         }
         context.page1list = results;
         complete();
   }

   // Return to page
   router.get('/',function(req,res){
      var callbackCount = 0;
      var context = {};
      var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
      getMyTable(res,mysql,context,complete);
      getMyList(res,mysql,context,complete);
      function complete() {
         callbackCount++;
         if(callbackCount >= 2){
            res.render('page1',context);
         }
      }
   }



}();
```

And then I have a `page1.handlebars` file:

```
<form id = "list_class">
   <fieldset>
      <label> Classses:
         <select name = "class_list" id = "class_list">
            {{#each page1list}}
            <option value = '{{class}}'>{{class}}</option>
            {{/each}}
         </select>
      </label>
   </fieldset>
</form>

<table class ="resultTable">
  <tbody id = "tableBody">
  {{#each page1table}}
     <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{class}}</td>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
     </tr> 
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: I should note that the results of `page1table` are displayed, but the results of `page1list` are not, though a call to `console.log(context.page1list);` in `function getMyList()` does print the expected list to the console. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't miss any part in page1.js?
I am curious why you didn't get any error while your brackets and curly braces were not properly closed?

for example:

```
 // Get the results of the second SQL statement
function getMyList(res, mysql, context, complete){
  mysql.pool.query("SELECT DISTINCT class from MyTable", function(error, results){
     if(error){
        res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
        res.end();
     }
     context.page1list = results;
     complete();
}
```

you were missing a `)` to close the query, and a `}` to close the function